# Need help in creating a file tree using jQueryFileTree.js

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a file tree structure using jquery.I came across this link

http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/

So i tried to use it.Below is the html source code of my file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jqueryFileTree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="css/jqueryFileTree.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#container_id').fileTree({ root: '/some/folder/' }, function(file) {
        alert(file);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container_id"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I open this page in a browser it shows a blank page.Nothing appears.Am I missing something?Please help.Thnx in advance.

Note:All the src of script tags are correct.

Comment: what errors do you see in your console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I resolved it.Thanks to Mozilla's FireBug.So I thought I should write the solution as well:-
In the Script Tag above,after specifying the root folder,we should use a connector which will take the path and fetch the file tree from this path along with all its child.

In my scenario,I used jsp connector.All these connectors can be downloaded
http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-fileTree/jquery.fileTree-1.01.zip

Make the below changes to above embedded script code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#container_id').fileTree({
root : '/home/abhinav',
script : 'jqueryFileTree.jsp'
}, function(file) {
alert(file);
});
});
```

Then our File tree is ready...:)

Comment: Is there the possibility to create a static file-tree from a given String in JavaScript? So without any server-side component?